# Which iMovie Projects Contain Legacy Media

Tags: imovie

I received a warning when opening iMovie that some projects contain legacy media and won't work in the future. It gave me a link to [Learn More](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209029). But it never told me which projects need to be updated. How can I determine what needs to be fixed?

Comment: Legacy media can include footage recorded with cameras like Flip Video cameras, footage from GoPro cameras recorded in the CineForm format, video files in the DivX format created with software, footage shot with many other older cameras, or files modified with older software.

Comment: I would like to known the answer also, as I have had the same message.

Comment: @Buscar Thanks, but that is what the Learn More link says. I do not have any of those (unless its files modified with older software). But I need to know which project files it is having a problem with.

Comment: I know, you think Apple would provide a file scan....they just leave you in the dark